# Android SQLite Error in Insertion Data?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-connection, sql-insert

I'm new on Android. I have some trouble with the insert statement in the database, when I'm running the application the values have not been inserted. Please someone can help..

```
public class tourDB{

    private static final String TAG = "tourDB";

    //DB information: It's name, and the table we are using.
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tourDatabase";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tourtable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //DataBase Fields here:
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "TripName";
    public static final String KEY_REASON = "Reason";
    public static final String KEY_CITY = "City";
    public static final String KEY_SOD = "StartingDate";
    public static final String KEY_AD = "ArrivalDate";
    public static final String KEY_BUDGET = "TotalBudget";
    public static final String KEY_HE = "HotelExp";
    public static final String KEY_TE = "TransportExp";
    public static final String KEY_FE = "FoodExp";
    public static final String KEY_SE = "ShoppingExp";
    public static final String KEY_OE = "OthersExp";
    public static final String KEY_REMAINBUDGET = "RemainingBudget";

    //DataBase Field numbers here (0 = KEY_ROWID, 1=...)
    /*public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
    public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
    public static final int COL_REASON = 2;
    public static final int COL_CITY = 3;
    public static final int COL_SOD = 4;
    public static final int COL_AD = 5;
    public static final int COL_BUDGET  = 6;
    public static final int COL_HE = 7;
    public static final int COL_TE = 8;
    public static final int COL_FE = 9;
    public static final int COL_SE = 10;
    public static final int COL_OE = 11;
    public static final int COL_REMAININGBUDGET = 12;
    */
    //public static final String[] LIST_KEYS = new String[]{"KEY_ROWID","KEY_NAME","KEY_BUDGET"};

    //public static final String DATABAE_UPGRADE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE;

    //Context of application who uses us.
    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    // Database Helper Class, Subclass: SQLiteOpenHelper

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" 
                    + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                    + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                    + KEY_REASON + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                    + KEY_CITY + " TEXT, " 
                    + KEY_SOD + " DATETIME, "
                    + KEY_AD + " DATETIME, "
                    + KEY_BUDGET + " TEXT not null, " 
                    + KEY_HE + " INTEGER, "
                    + KEY_TE + " INTEGER, "
                    + KEY_FE + " INTEGER, "
                    + KEY_SE + " INTEGER, " 
                    + KEY_OE + " INTEGER, " 
                    + KEY_REMAINBUDGET + "INTEGER);"
            );  
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
        public tourDB(Context c){

            this.ourContext = c;
        }

    // Open And Close Method

        public tourDB open() throws SQLException{

            ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;

        }

        public void close(){

            ourHelper.close();

        }

        public long createEntry(String TripName, String TripReason, String cityName, String SD, String AD, String budget, 
                                int HE, int TE, int FE, int SE, int OE, int remainBudget) {

            ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
            v.put(KEY_NAME, TripName);
            v.put(KEY_REASON, TripReason);
            v.put(KEY_CITY, cityName);
            v.put(KEY_SOD, SD);
            v.put(KEY_AD, AD);
            v.put(KEY_BUDGET, budget);
            v.put(KEY_HE, HE);
            v.put(KEY_TE, TE);
            v.put(KEY_FE, FE); 
            v.put(KEY_SE, SE);
            v.put(KEY_OE, OE);
            v.put(KEY_REMAINBUDGET, remainBudget);

            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,v);
            return 0;
        }
}
```

I'm sending data but it didn't work. Showing Error that a table has no column Column_name.
This the class where I'm Sending data.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch(arg0.getId()) {  

        case R.id.button_getdate:


            //editText_startingdate.setText(newtime);

            break;
        case R.id.button_createNew:

            boolean didItWork = true;

            cityName = editText_cityactivity.getText().toString();
            SD = editText_startingdate.getText().toString();
            AD = null;
            budget = editText_budget.getText().toString();
            HE = TE = FE = SE = OE = 0;
            remainBudget = Integer.parseInt(budget);



            try {
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(TripName, TripReason, cityName, SD, AD, budget, HE, TE, FE, SE, OE, remainBudget);
                entry.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (didItWork) {
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("New Profile" + "Successfully Created");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);

                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button_back:

            Intent openCreateNewActivity_1 = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.CREATENEWACTIVITY_1");
            startActivity(openCreateNewActivity_1);

            break;
        }

    }
```

I don't find out the mistaken in my code. Can AnyOne Help

Comment: can you initialize `entry` object for your `SQLITEDATABASE`...???

Comment: No.You are trying to i nsert value with column Column_name, but the Column_name does not exist in your table. Can you pls share your full stack trace?

Comment: Yes Initialize Object for entry...

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" 
     + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
     + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
     + KEY_REASON + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
     + KEY_CITY + " TEXT, " 
     + KEY_SOD + " DATETIME, "
     + KEY_AD + " DATETIME, "
     + KEY_BUDGET + " TEXT not null, " 
     + KEY_HE + " INTEGER, "
     + KEY_TE + " INTEGER, "
     + KEY_FE + " INTEGER, "
     + KEY_SE + " INTEGER, " 
     + KEY_OE + " INTEGER, " 
     + KEY_REMAINBUDGET + " INTEGER);"
   ); 
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" 
           ...
           + KEY_OE + " INTEGER, "
           + KEY_REMAINBUDGET + "INTEGER);"
```

The name of the last column is `RemainingBudgetINTEGER`.
You forgot a space character.

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" 
     + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
     + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
     + KEY_REASON + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
     + KEY_CITY + " TEXT, " 
     + KEY_SOD + " DATETIME, "
     + KEY_AD + " DATETIME, "
     + KEY_BUDGET + " TEXT not null, " 
     + KEY_HE + " INTEGER, "
     + KEY_TE + " INTEGER, "
     + KEY_FE + " INTEGER, "
     + KEY_SE + " INTEGER, " 
     + KEY_OE + " INTEGER, " 
     + KEY_REMAINBUDGET + " INTEGER);"
   ); 
  }

Comment: The database will not change until you remove and reinstall the app. And "not inserting" is useless without the exact error message.

Comment: 12-01 01:07:46.666: E/SQLiteLog(944): (1) table tourtable has no column named RemainingBudget

Comment: 12-01 01:07:47.126: E/SQLiteDatabase(944): Error inserting FoodExp=0 ArrivalDate=null TransportExp=0 HotelExp=0 ShoppingExp=0 RemainingBudget=50000 OthersExp=0 TotalBudget=50000 TripName=bd StartingDate=12.12.12. City=dhaka Reason=Travel
12-01 01:07:47.126: E/SQLiteDatabase(944): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tourtable has no column named RemainingBudget (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tourtable(FoodExp,ArrivalDate,TransportExp,HotelExp,ShoppingExp,RemainingBudget,OthersExp,TotalBudget,TripName,StartingDate,City,Reason) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: You still have the old database. `onCreate` will not be called again if the database file already exists.

Comment: how to erase old database ?? @CL

Comment: Android allows you to remove an app's data.